# How do I remove an object from an array on click? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm adding hours and dates which are displayed in a list and then pushing the values to an array.
A button is created next to each list item and I want to be able to remove the specific list item on click.
I've tried splice, slice and remove but I'm not able to make it work as I want.

```
let vacationList = [];
  $('#add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  
    let vacationHours = $('#vacationHours').val();
    let vacationDates = document.querySelector("#vacationDates").value;
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = vacationHours + "h - " + vacationDates;
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.className = "fa fa-minus-circle";
    const ul = document.querySelector(".list");
    ul.appendChild(li); 
    li.appendChild(button);

  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault() 

    ??

  });

vacationList.push({vacationHours: Number(vacationHours), vacationDates: vacationDates});
```

Comment: `e.target` inside your event handler will return the element firing the event. probably just doing something like `e.target.closest('li')` will give you the element to remove

Answer (score 0):

`Element.remove()` should work for the dom element. If you want also remove from array please provide the adding to array code.

```js
$('#add').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let vacationHours = $('#vacationHours').val();
  let vacationDates = document.querySelector("#vacationDates").value;
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = vacationHours + "h - " + vacationDates;
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.className = "fa fa-minus-circle";
  const ul = document.querySelector(".list");
  ul.appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(button);

  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    this.closest("li").remove();
  });

});
```